# Me or I proper usage in a formal sentence

Tags: pronouns

The President recently sent a letter with the following sentence. I think the last word in the sentence is incorrect and should be “me”. Would someone please clarify this for me please?

“It is a terrible thing you are doing, but you will have to live with it, not I.”

Comment: In a simple negative tag, either _I_ or _me_ is equally appropriate. _I_ is right because it's the subject of the (deleted) verb phrase, and _me_ is right because that's the default form, correct anywhere except immediately before a verb that agrees with it, when _I_ is required.

Comment: The sentence is saying correctly that "It is **not I** who will have to live with it."

Answer (score 1):

It's clear that the letter had been read over by some staffers with fairly good English credentials (eg, no spelling errors have been pointed out so far).

Whether "me" or "I" is appropriate depends on how you read it. One could read it as "you will have to live with it, I will not have to live with it", in which case "I" is correct. But it could be interpreted as "the person who will have to live with it is not me" (or one of several other mappings).

Comment: I figured that someone more knowledgeable than the author of the letter would have reviewed it, however, the part I pointed out struck me as improper.

Comment: It looks fine to me.